# Use htaccess to remove any sub directories in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, expressionengine

I run an Expression Engine site that will load an article page regardless of any made up sub directory names typed into the address bar.

For example all these addresses:

```
http://hellothere.example.com/health/mental/depression
http://cats.example.com/health/mental/depression
http://dogs.example.com/health/mental/depression
http://www.batman.example.com/health/mental/depression
http://www.1.2.3.4.5.6.example.com/health/mental/depression
```

Will load `example.com/health/mental/depression`

Obviously, this is less than ideal for SEO since I've got a potentially unlimited number of duplicate URLs.

I am trying to figure out how to use htaccess to strip anything before example.com and replace it with just www.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this with htaccess. The way to do this is to set up a wildcard dns record so that all requests (*.example.com) are all directed to the same server.

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Wildcard_Subdomains